# How do I show all boxplot labels

Tags: r, boxplot

I've created a box plot, the data on the left is the continous variable and the data on the right has about 10 unique options. When I create the boxplot I cannot see the labels. How do I make it show all the labels, possibly vertically?

```
boxplot(data$Rate ~ as.factor(data$Purpose))
```

I've looked around and cannot work out what im trying to follow.

Answer (score 47):

You can add argument `las=2` to function `boxplot()` to make all labels perpendicular to axis.

```
df<-data.frame(Rate=rnorm(100),Purpose=rep(letters[1:10],each=10))
boxplot(df$Rate~df$Purpose,las=2)
```

If your label names are long then you should adjust also plot margins.

```
par(mar=c(7,5,1,1))
boxplot(df$Rate~df$Purpose,las=2)
```

Comment: The `las` strategy is limited to 4 angles. The FAQ `text( ... , srt= |angle|, xpd=TRUE)` strategy gives you 360 possible angles

Answer (score 8):

When you are wanting to precisely specify your axes labels, here's the strategy I use:

```
##Generate a boxplot without axes
boxplot(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays, axes=FALSE)

##Add in a y-axis
axis(2, seq(0,25, 5), seq(0, 25, 5))

##Add in an x-axis
##las=2 changes the orientation
axis(1, 1:6, paste("Big Label", 1:6), las=2)
```

Answer (score 4):

There is an entry in the R FAQ on how to rotate axis labels in base graphics :

http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-create-rotated-axis-labels_003f

But I personaly would prefer to use `ggplot2`, which makes it easier :

```
data <- data.frame(Rate=rnorm(1:1000),Purpose=sample(c("foo","bar","baz"),1000,replace=TRUE))
ggplot(data, aes(x=factor(Purpose), y=Rate)) + geom_boxplot() + theme(axis.text.x  = element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Why does this answer appear first? It has the least votes, is not the accepted answer, and recommends a different plotting tool altogether, which is unhelpful for future readers who just want to *minimally* fix the problem described.